# C programming read a integer from command line input string

Tags: c, string

I just started programming and have a question. I have a example input from command line: "number:10" which is "number:" followed by a number. I want to check if the character after "number:" is a number:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 

if(isdigit(*argv[2]+7)){
  printf("correct");  
}
return 0;
}
```

It doesn't work. How can I read only the number in the input string?

Comment: Watch out: what happens if there are fewer than three command line arguments?  What happens if `argv2` has fewer than 7 characters?

Comment: So, you are reading in a string from the command line  argument that would be something like "number:10" and you only want to read the number in the input string? Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: @aschepler Hi, thanks for the heads up, in my actual program I will do these error check you mentioned. The only part I don't understand is how to compare the number in that string

Comment: @aschepler Yes!

Comment: What about `if (sscanf(argv[2], "number:%d", &AnInt) == 1) {...` (after making sure `argc` is at least 3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*argv[2]` is `'n'`. `*(argv[2]+7)` is correct